# The "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::__construct()" method is considered internal

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have made a phpunit test that looks like this:

```php
class MyTest extends KernelTestCase
{

    /**
     * MyTest constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // ...
    }

    public function testSomething()
    {
        self::assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

But executing the test shows this warning:

```
$ ./bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 8.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 630 ms, Memory: 6.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Other deprecation notices (1)

  1x: The "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::__construct()" method is considered internal This method is not covered by the backward compatibility promise for PHPUnit. It may change without further notice. You should not extend it from "App\Tests\MyTest".
```

How do I get rid of that warning? I might use`setUpBeforeClass()`, but then I would have to make all properties of the unit test static even if they are only used in the tests. I could use `setUp()` but this method is executed once for each test and I need the initialization code that is supposed to be in the constructor executed only one time. Is using static properties considered a good practice in this case? Is this the way I am expected to code my unit tests?

Comment: Tests should be isolated from one another. It isn't wrong to call `setUp` before every test, despite performing the same initialization every time.

Answer (score 0):

remove parent::__construct(); line